# Dynamically creating a imageButton Click event? Non-Invocable Error

Tags: c#, .net

I followed this similar post. However, it didn't work and is giving me an error.

[How can i create dynamic button click event on dynamic button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6187944/how-can-i-create-dynamic-button-click-event-on-dynamic-button)

The error is:
"Non-invocable member 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.OnClientClick' cannot be used like a method."

The code I am trying is:

```
ImageButton appIcon2 = new ImageButton();
appIcon2.OnClientClick(){ }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on client click takes javascript function 
i.e `myImgButton.OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure?');";`

if you want to do "Click" function just do this

```
ImageButton appIcon2 = new ImageButton();
appIcon2.Click  += new System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventHandler(appIcon2_Click);

void appIcon2_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)

    {

       // Your Code here

    }
```

if you want to access this image button you can cast sender as image button as follows

```
void appIcon2_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)

    {

       ImageButton imgBtn= sender as ImageButton;
       string id= imgBtn.ID;



    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`OnClientClick` accepts a string value i.e. it is supposed to point to a javascript code block.

you can either do this.

```
appIcon2.OnClientClick = "alert('s')";
```

or

```
appIcon2.OnClientClick = "myMethod()";
```

where `myMethod()` is a javascript function defined in the html `head` or `body` of the page i.e.

```
function myMethod(){
   alert('s');
}
```

as for the link that you have posted, it simply says how can you directly add an event handler to a button. i.e.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender , EventArgs)
{
   ImageButton appIcon2 = new ImageButton();
   appIcon2.Click += new System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventHandler(btn_Click);
}

void btn_Click(object sender, System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
   //your logic
}
```

note that `Click` is an [event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720049%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). it is associated with server side controls