# How to Use Dynamically Created Button/textBox in C# Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void createButton()
{
    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {    
        Button b = new Button();
        b.Name = i.ToString();
        b.Text = "Button" + i.ToString();
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(b);
    }

}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    createButton();
}
```

I Used this code to create some buttons on runtime , now how can i use those created buttons to perform diffrent actions? Im kindz new to this so please help me , very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 8):

You can assign an event handler to the click event:

```
b.Click += SomeMethod;
```

`SomeMethod` must have the following signature:

```
void SomeMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Comment: And a shorter example for those who cares: `b.Click += (sender, e) => 
                {
                    var clickedButton = (Button)sender;
                };` =)

Comment: @Mario When you have an anonymous event handler you can avoid casting `sender` and just close over the button itself.

Comment: @Servy Yepp, I'm aware of that =) Just wanted to be more explicit and show what the sender is. I was guessing the OP didn't know about closures.

Answer (score 1):

When you create your button, you need to subscribe to the `Click` event like this :

```
Button b = new Button();
b.Click += new EventHandler(b_Click);
// or
b.Click += b_Click;
// or
b.Click += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) {/* any action */});
// or
b.Click += (s, e) => { /* any action */ };

void b_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // any action
}
```

This is something that is automatically done when your are is the designer in Visual Studio, and you click on a button to create the method `button1_Click`.
You can search in the Designer.cs of your form, you will find an equivalent line:

```
button1.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click);
```

Related question:

- [How can i create dynamic button click event on dynamic button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6187944/how-can-i-create-dynamic-button-click-event-on-dynamic-button)

Comment: can you please evaluate this a litle more in detail :) actually im trying to make a simple form , which creates  fields as may as user wants & then the user can perform action between them , like if the user wants 2 textBox , he writes 3 & the textBox are created on runtime , & then those 2 textBox i.e textBox1 & textBox2 can get any value & the third textBox shows the added result. how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
b.Click += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   Button clickedButton = (Button)sender; //gets the clicked button
});
```

Comment: You can simplify the syntax to just `b.Click += (s, e) => { /* code */  };`