# Assigning code to a variable

Tags: c#, variables

Is it possible to make a variable, and assign a line of code to it, such as:

```
ButtonClicked = (MessageBox.Show("Hello, World!"));
```

... so when I use the variable, it will execute the line of code.

Comment: +1 for the rare combination of being new to coding and asking a good question: you understand what you want to do and explain it well, you just don't know the term for it so you can't find it on your own.

Comment: The term you're looking for is a [delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17sde2xt(v=vs.90).aspx).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6187944/how-can-i-create-dynamic-button-click-event-on-dynamic-button check this out, i think there is enough explanaition you will need. Asp works almost like winforms in that matter.

Comment: Sounds a lot like blocks in Objective-c

Answer (score 89):

You could assign it to an [`Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like this:

```
var ButtonClicked = new Action(() => MessageBox.Show("hi"));
```

Then call it:

```
ButtonClicked();
```

For completeness (in regards to the various comments)...

As Erik stated, you could execute multiple lines of code:

```
var ButtonClicked = new Action(() =>
{
    MessageBox.Show("hi");

    MessageBox.Show("something else");  // something more useful than another popup ;)
});
```

As Tim stated, you could omit the `Action` keyword

```
Action ButtonClicked = () => MessageBox.Show("hi");

Action ButtonClicked = () =>
{
    // multiple lines of code
};
```

To address KRyan's comment, regarding the empty parentheses, that represents the list of parameters you want to be able to send to the Action *(in this case, none)*.

If, for instance, you wanted to specify the message to show, you could add "message" as a parameter *(note that I changed* `Action` *to* [`Action<string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) *in order to specify a single string parameter)*:

```
Action<string> ButtonClicked = (message) => MessageBox.Show(message);

ButtonClicked("hello world!");
```

Comment: `Action ButtonClicked = () => MessageBox.Show("hi");` is equivalent and IMO nicer (add parens if you prefer)

Comment: It is also possible for the action to resolve to more than a single line of code.

Comment: Hes probably using WinForms and therefore this isnt this helpful.

Comment: As it is also possible for the *variable* to return a value using [`Func`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960(v=vs.110).aspx).  `Func GetValue = () => return 1;`, and thus `bool isTrue = GetValue() == 1;`.

Comment: @CSharpie I'm not sure that making that assumption is helpful for the OP.

Comment: @CSharpie Why couldn't the OP use this in `WinForms`?

Comment: @GrantWinney button.Click needs an action with object and eventargs as parameters e.g. button.Click = (s,o) => { ... }

Comment: @CSharpie I see what you're saying. If he's actually attaching this to a `Button.Click` event, and not storing it in a variable which he happened to name `ButtonClicked`.

Comment: I think this answer could use a brief explanation of the `(...args...) => ...code...` syntax. With no args, the `() =>` may seem like an opaque and monolithic piece of syntax.

Answer (score 50):

In your case, you want to use a `delegate`.

Let's see how a delegate works and how we can get to an easier form by understanding its concept:

```
// Create a normal function
void OnButtonClick()
{
    MessageBox.Show("Hello World!");
}
// Now we create a delegate called ButtonClick
delegate void ButtonClick();
```

You see, the delegate takes the form of a normal function but without any arguments (It could take any amount of arguments just like any other method, but for the sake of simplicity, it doesn't).

Now, let's use what we have; we will define the delegate just as we define any other variable:

```
ButtonClick ButtonClicked = new ButtonClick(OnButtonClick);
```

We basically created a new variable called ButtonClicked, that has a type of ButtonClick (which is a delegate) and that when used, will execute the method in the OnButtonClick() method.
To use it we simply call: `ButtonClicked();`

So the whole code would be:

```
delegate void ButtonClick();

void OnButtonClick()
{
    MessageBox.Show("Hello World!");
}

void Foo()
{
    ButtonClick ButtonClicked = new ButtonClick(OnButtonClick);
    ButtonClicked(); // Execute the function.
}
```

From here, we can move to lambda expressions and see how they could be useful in your situation:
There are many delegates already defined by .NET libraries, with some like Action, which do not accept any parameter and does no return a value. It is defined as `public delegate void Action();`
You can always use it to your needs instead of the need of defining a new delegate every time. In the previous context for example, you could had just written

```
Action ButtonClicked = new Action(OnButtonClick);
ButtonClicked();
```

which would had done the same.
Now that you saw different ways of how to use delegates, let's use our first lambda expression. Lambda expressions are anonymous functions; so, they are normal functions but without a name. They are of those forms:

```
x => DoSomethingWithX(x);
(x) => DoSomethingWithX(x);
(x,y) => DoSometingWithXY(x,y);
() => Console.WriteLine("I do not have parameters!");
```

In our case, we do not have any parameters so we will use the last expression. We can use this just as the OnButtonClick function, but we get the advantage of not having a named function. We can instead do something like this:

```
Action ButtonClicked = new Action( () => MessageBox.Show("Hello World!") );
```

or even easier,

```
Action ButtonClicked = () => MessageBox.Show("Hello World!");
```

then simply call `ButtonClicked();` Of course you can also have multi-lines of code, but I do not want to confuse you more. It would look like this though:

```
Action ButtonClicked = () => 
{
    MessageBox.Show("Hello World!");
};
ButtonClicked();
```

You could also play around, for example, you can execute a function like this:

```
new Action(() => MessageBox.Show("Hello World!"))();
```

Sorry for the long post, hope it was not too confusing :)

EDIT: I forgot to mention that an alternate form which, even though not often used, could make lambda expressions easier to understand:

```
new Action(delegate() {
    Console.WriteLine("I am parameterless");
})();
```

Also, using generics:

```
// Defines a delegate that has one parameter of type string. You could pass as many parameters as you want.
new Action<string>(delegate(string x) {
    Console.WriteLine(x);
})("I am a string parameter!");
```

In turn you could use lambda expressions, but you do not need (but might in some cases) to define the type of the parameter, for example, the code above could simply be written as:

```
new Action<string>(x => {
    Console.WriteLine(x);
})("I am a string parameter!");
```

or:

```
new Action<string>(x => Console.WriteLine(x))("I am a string parameter!");
```

EDIT2:
`Action<string>` is a representation of `public void delegate Action(string obj);`
`Action<string,string>` is a representation of `public void delegate Action(string obj, string obj2);`
In general, `Action<T>` is a representation of `public void delegate Action<T>(T obj);`

EDIT3:
I know the post has been here for a while, but I think this is really cool to not mention:
You can do this, which is mostly related to your question:

```
dynamic aFunction = (Func<string, DialogResult>)MessageBox.Show;
aFunction("Hello, world!");
```

or simply:

```
Func<string, DialogResult> aFunction = MessageBox.Show;
aFunction("Hello, world!");
```

Answer (score 8):

The [`Lazy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class is specifically designed to represent a value that won't be computed until you ask for it.  You construct it by providing a method that defines how it should be constructed, but it will handle executing that method no more than once (even in the face of multiple threads requesting the value) and simply returning the already constructed value for any additional requests:

```
var foo = new Lazy<DialogResult>(()=>MessageBox.Show("Hello, World!"));

var result = foo.Value;
```

Comment: Remember that `Lazy` should be used for values that require a lot of processing power, and that you should not use them for interaction (because the semantics of `.Value` is that it returns a value, similar to a property, not an (interactive) action). A delegate should be used for such actions instead.

Comment: @Abel No, it's *not* for values that require a lot of processing power, it's for any value that you would like to defer the initialization of until it is asked for, while not ever initializing that value more than once.  Here the value of `Value` *is* used; it is the `DialogResult` received from showing the message box.  The primary difference between this solution and using a delegate is whether the value should be re-computed each time it is requested or not.  My interpretation of the requirements was that this is conceptually initializing a value, not an *operation* to be repeated.

Comment: `Lazy` can easily be wrongly used. It has overhead of itself, using it "just" to defer a small task will invoke more overhead than it gains. Showing messageboxes from a property is (imo) bad practice in general, regardless of `Lazy`. Btw, from MSDN, I quote: _"Use lazy initialization to defer the creation of a large or resource-intensive object"_. You can disagree with that, but that was what it was designed for originally.

Comment: @Abel The performance overhead for `Lazy` in a context like this is certainly negligible; it will pale in comparison to the time spent waiting for a human to click on a message box.  It mostly comes down to the real requirements of the underlying application; the vagueness of the question makes an objectively correct answer impossible.  This is one interpretation of the question.  As for doing a lot of work in a property getter being bad; apparently you're fundamentally opposed to the entire design of `Lazy`.  You're welcome to that opinion.

Comment: Sorry, you must have misunderstood me. Certainly, with `MessageBox`  the overhead is negligible (I just wouldn't use UI inside a property). I meant small tasks in general (like deferring `2 + 3 * 4 / i`), where the overhead of creating the closure is greater than the calculation itself. And I think I fully embrace `Lazy`, in fact we use it a lot in F# (little less in C#) and we have learned the hard way that you have to be careful with it, esp. in respect with performance.

Comment: @Abel The proposal of using *just* a delegate, instead of having `Lazy` control a delegate, has all of those same performance characteristics.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Choosing between a delegate and `Lazy` should be based on the similar semantics of choosing between a method and a property or field (i.e., does it yield a value, or is it an (inter)action). Anyway, sorry to hijack your thread, I never meant to oppose to `Lazy` in general, just to warn about its (proper) use and I seem to have failed to make my point clearly.

Answer (score 4):

The way I'm reading your question, this is in the context of GUI controls?

If this is in WPF, take a look at the "right" way to handle commands from controls:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

...but that can be a pain and overkill. For a simpler general case, you might be looking for an event handler, like:

```
myButton.Click += (o, e) => MessageBox.Show("Hello, World!");
```

That event handler can be handled a variety of ways. The above example uses an anonymous function, but you could also do:

```
Action<object, RoutedEventArgs> sayHello = (o, e) => MessageBox.Show("Hello, World");
myButton.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(sayHello);
```

...just like you were asking, with a function (or here, "Action", since it returns void) assigned as a variable.

Answer (score 2):

You can assign C# code to a variable, compiling it at runtime and run the code:

- Write your code:

  ```
  // Assign C# code to the code variable.
  string code = @"
  using System;

  namespace First
  {
      public class Program
      {
          public static void Main()
          {
              " +
              "Console.WriteLine(\"Hello, world!\");"
              + @"
          }
      }
  }
  ";
  ```
- Create the provider and parameters of the compiler:

  ```
  CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
  CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
  ```
- Define parameters of the compiler:

  ```
  // Reference to System.Drawing library
  parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Drawing.dll");
  // True - memory generation, false - external file generation
  parameters.GenerateInMemory = true;
  // True - exe file generation, false - dll file generation
  parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;
  ```
- Compile assembly:

  ```
  CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, code);
  ```
- Check errors:

  ```
  if (results.Errors.HasErrors)
  {
          StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

          foreach (CompilerError error in results.Errors)
          {
                  sb.AppendLine(String.Format("Error ({0}): {1}", error.ErrorNumber, error.ErrorText));
          }

          throw new InvalidOperationException(sb.ToString());
  }
  ```
- Get assembly, type and the Main method:

  ```
  Assembly assembly = results.CompiledAssembly;
  Type program = assembly.GetType("First.Program");
  MethodInfo main = program.GetMethod("Main");
  ```
- Run it:

  ```
  main.Invoke(null, null);
  ```

Reference:

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/715891/Compiling-Csharp-Code-at-Runtime

Comment: I don't think dynamic code compilation was at all relevant to the asked question.