# ASP.net button click doesn't fire

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

When I click on button A, I create a button B, and when I click on the button B, the Click event doesn't fire. why?

```
Button A = new Button();
A.Click += A_Click;

A_Click:
Button B = new Button();
B.Click += B_Click;

B_Click:
//never fires
```

Comment: Try the method here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6187944/how-can-i-create-dynamic-button-click-event-on-dynamic-button

Comment: Where you attach these events??

Comment: Can you post all relevant code to have a look?

Comment: Might be a problem related to dynamically created controls. You have to re-create them at the beginning of the PostBack in order to work correctly. Can you put the buttons on the page in markup with Visible set to false and just change Visible to true if you want to show a button?