# How to fire onclick event on a dynamically created button

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I've got a Button called ButtonCreator when you click on it a click event called ButtonCreator_OnClick is fired, inside the function I've created a button dynamically, now how do I create on click event for that button?

the code:

```
private void ButtonCreator_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Button button = new Button();
button.Click += (object s, EventArgs eb) => {};
}
```

now when I click on the button the page is post back and the control is gone, how do I make the function inside the event handler work?

Comment: Are you using [`WebForms`](https://www.asp.net/web-forms)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6187944/how-can-i-create-dynamic-button-click-event-on-dynamic-button

Comment: @Givi yes I'm using WebForms

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i create dynamic button click event on dynamic button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6187944/how-can-i-create-dynamic-button-click-event-on-dynamic-button)

Comment: The button (or any other dynamic control) is lost on PostBack unless it is recreated. If it is not it will not execute the method.