# Run JavaScript function on change of dynamically generated asp checkbox state

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm generating asp checkbox as:

```
var chkbx1 = new CheckBox();
chkbx1.ID = "cb" + tableRow[1].ToString();
```

And I want to run some JavaScript function say `myFunction()` on change of checkbox state. Is there any way this could be done?

Comment: Isn't there an "OnClientClick" property for this control?

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6187944/how-can-i-create-a-dynamic-button-click-event-on-a-dynamic-button) answer. It's the same thing but instead of the click event it will be the checked event.

Example:

```
var chkbx1 = new CheckBox();
chkbx1.ID = "cb" + tableRow[1].ToString();
chkbx1.Checked += (s,e) => { your code; };
container.Controls.Add(button);
```

Didn't test it's probably what you want. Although, this is server side event. Do you really want a client side event (I mean, it's a server side control, so you might do either)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it from the server, you can add an onclick or onchange event handler via the server:

```
checkbox.Attributes.Add("onclick", "function(this);");
```

OR:

```
checkbox.Attributes.Add("onchange", "function(this);");
```

Or simply attach to client-side elements on the client using the ID via JavaScript, or by tag via jQuery.