# C#form app making events on buttons from backend

Tags: c#

I'm working on a c# winforms application.I have created buttons from the back end, like the following:

```
Button b = new Button();
```

How can I attach a click to each button that is created from the back end, that each button when clicked, a picture should become visible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create a dynamic button click event on a dynamic button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6187944/how-can-i-create-a-dynamic-button-click-event-on-a-dynamic-button)

Answer (score 2):

You can register events like this:

```
Button b = new Button();
b.Click += customButton_Click;
public void customButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // code here
}
```

Here the `+=` operator will helps you to register the [event handlers.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-create-event-handlers-at-run-time-for-windows-forms)