# How to call Menustrip items from toolstrip click event

Tags: c#, toolstrip, menustrip

this is my code and from toolstrip click event i want to call the menustrip sub items
Ex: Menu like : Settings -> User. I want to call user_click event from toolstip click

```
private void tbrIUC1_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
{
    string menuname="mnuuser";
    e.ClickedItem.Click += new EventHandler(menuname + "_Click");
}
```

Comment: Subscribing the Click event is a grave mistake.  That must only be done once, belongs in the constructor or the InitializeComponent() method.  Simply call the click event handler directly, like user_click(sender, EventArgs.Empty);

Answer (score 0):

You can use anonymous delegate:

```
private void tbrIUC1_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
{
    string menuname="mnuuser";
    e.ClickedItem.Click += (s, ev) => { your code when clicked };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From another stackoverflow post I got the following working for me:

```
ButtonName.Click += (se, ev) => button1_Click(se, ev);
```

Link to "inspiration" [How can I create a dynamic button click event on a dynamic button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6187944/how-can-i-create-a-dynamic-button-click-event-on-a-dynamic-button)
Look for the answer from A9S6 and the comment to this from Scott Beeson

***EDIT***

To call a function BASED on the function name (string) I got the following article:
http://www.vcskicks.com/call-function.php
I haven't got it working for me by now but I wanted to share a possible solution

If all fails: I recommend declaring a new method with a Switch that gets the control and the string passed

Comment: Not working, See actually i'm having some short cuts in toolstrip and what name given to that menustrip items same i gave for toolstirp item also. When i'm clicking toolstrip i will get the menustrip item name but i want to call that click event dynamically with use of string "_Click" so for that its not working

Comment: Quick answer: use a switch(menuname)                                      Long answer: I'm gonna check out what I can accomplish :)